# Read items that were created by the user cannot be enabled

Tags: access, read

We're trying to enable a setting in a group on Sharepoint

[image]

When trying to save this we get the following error message:

[image]

Did anyone have any experience with this on how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: The M365 version